# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: While publishing in Jboss 6.1.0

Tags: classloader, jboss6.x

I am getting the following stacktrace while i publishing the war in Jboss 6.1.0 (using JDK 7).

This war is working perfectly in Tomcat 7(Using JDK 7).

Please se the below error Log

11:46:15,715 WARN  [org.jboss.detailed.classloader.ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObject: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERObject has interface org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Encodable as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) [:1.7.0_04]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.access$200(BaseClassLoader.java:52) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:650) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader$2.run(BaseClassLoader.java:609) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_04]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:608) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassLocally(BaseClassLoader.java:585) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseDelegateLoader.loadClass(BaseDelegateLoader.java:156) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.doLoadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:141) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.filter.FilteredDelegateLoader.loadClass(FilteredDelegateLoader.java:132) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoadingTask$ThreadTask.run(ClassLoadingTask.java:461) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.nextTask(ClassLoaderManager.java:262) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.ClassLoaderManager.process(ClassLoaderManager.java:161) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:280) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoaderDomain.loadClass(BaseClassLoaderDomain.java:1172) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClassFromDomain(BaseClassLoader.java:886) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.doLoadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:505) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:450) [jboss-classloader.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) [:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442) [:1.7.0_04]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808) [:1.7.0_04]
    at

Can anyone help me on this for resloving this issue?? I am new to Jboss 6.X

Please help me

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please.. Your soon reply will be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your war-file is probably composed out of bouncycastels bcprov-jdk15 in different versions. ASN1Encodable has been an abstract class in version 1.45 but was an interface in 1.49. DERObject just in 1.45 but not in 1.49. Your war file somehow contains the DERObject from 1.45 and the ASN1Encodable from 1.49 - those are not compatible.

Anyway, it's not necessarily 1.45 and 1.49, but I had a similar problem with these version.